# SGDK collision issue

Tags: c

I have tried to implement some collision for SGDK (as show below) and it seems that when you move down into something, it shoots you through the collision rather that keeping you out.

```
#include <genesis.h>
#include <resources.h>

char info [10];

const u16 LENGTH_OF_LEVELCOL_ARRAY = 40;
const u8 STARTING_TOWN_COLLISION[1120] =
{
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
};


u16 ind = TILE_USER_INDEX;

#define ANIM_IDLE 0
#define ANIM_DOWN 1
#define ANIM_UP 2
#define ANIM_RIGHT_OR_LEFT 3

#define player_height 16
#define player_width 16

#define PLAYER_COLBOX_LEFT 0
#define PLAYER_COLBOX_RIGHT 16
#define PLAYER_COLBOX_TOP 0
#define PLAYER_COLBOX_BOTTOM 16

#define SOLID_TILE 1
#define NON_SOLID_TILE 0

Map* level_town_1a;
Sprite* player;

int player_x = 152;
int player_y = 104;

bool player_move_left = FALSE;
bool player_move_right = FALSE;
bool player_move_up = FALSE;
bool player_move_down = FALSE;



static void handleInput();
static void collision();

int main()
{
    // Display Map

    VDP_loadTileSet(&starting_town_tileset, ind, DMA);
    PAL_setPalette(PAL1, starting_town_map_palette.data, DMA);
    level_town_1a = MAP_create(&starting_town_map, BG_B, TILE_ATTR_FULL(PAL1, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ind));
    MAP_scrollTo(level_town_1a, 0, 0);

    // Displaying Sprite

    SPR_init();
    PAL_setPalette(PAL0, adam_sprite_palette.data, DMA);
    player = SPR_addSprite (&adam, player_x, player_y, TILE_ATTR(PAL0, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE));
    SPR_setAnim(player, ANIM_IDLE);


    // Playing Music
    XGM_setLoopNumber(-1);
    SND_startPlay_XGM(test_theme);

    while(1)
    {
        handleInput();
        collision();
        SPR_update();

        SYS_doVBlankProcess();
    }
}

static void handleInput()
{
    u16 value = JOY_readJoypad(JOY_1);

 // D-PAD CONTROL -------------------------------------------------

    if (value & BUTTON_RIGHT)
    {
        player_move_right = TRUE;
        player_move_left = FALSE;
        SPR_setAnim(player, ANIM_RIGHT_OR_LEFT);
        SPR_setHFlip(player, FALSE);
    }

    else if (value & BUTTON_LEFT)
    {
        player_move_right = FALSE;
        player_move_left = TRUE;
        SPR_setAnim(player, ANIM_RIGHT_OR_LEFT);
        SPR_setHFlip(player, TRUE);
    }
    
    else
    {
        player_move_left = FALSE;
        player_move_right = FALSE;
    }

    if (value & BUTTON_UP)
    {
        player_move_up = TRUE;
        player_move_down = FALSE;
        SPR_setAnim(player, ANIM_UP);
    }

    else if (value & BUTTON_DOWN)
    {
        player_move_down = TRUE;
        player_move_up = FALSE;
        SPR_setAnim(player, ANIM_DOWN);
    }

    else
    {
        player_move_down = FALSE;
        player_move_up = FALSE;
    }

 //IDLE ANIMATION CODE -------------------------------------------------

    if (! (value & BUTTON_LEFT) && ! (value & BUTTON_RIGHT) && ! (value & BUTTON_UP) && ! (value & BUTTON_DOWN) )
    {
        SPR_setAnim(player, ANIM_IDLE);
    }


    SPR_setPosition(player, player_x, player_y);
}

static void collision()
{
    s16 i;
    s16 array_index;

    s16 player_left_collision_coord;
    s16 player_right_collision_coord;
    s16 player_top_collision_coord;
    s16 player_bottom_collision_coord;


    s16 xtile_coord_left_collision_player;
    s16 xtile_coord_right_collision_player;
    s16 ytile_coord_top_collision_player;
    s16 ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player;


    u16 array_index_topleft_colbox;
    u16 array_index_topright_colbox;
    u16 array_index_bottomleft_colbox;
    u16 array_index_bottomright_colbox;


    u8 tile_collision_type_topleft;
    u8 tile_collision_type_topright;
    u8 tile_collision_type_bottomleft;
    u8 tile_collision_type_bottomright;


    s16 blocked_coord;
    

    if (player_move_left)
    {
        player_x -= 1;
                
        player_left_collision_coord = player_x + PLAYER_COLBOX_LEFT;
        xtile_coord_left_collision_player = player_left_collision_coord / 8;

        player_top_collision_coord = player_y + PLAYER_COLBOX_TOP;
        ytile_coord_top_collision_player = player_top_collision_coord / 8;

        player_bottom_collision_coord = player_y + PLAYER_COLBOX_BOTTOM;
        ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player = player_bottom_collision_coord / 8;

        for (i = ytile_coord_top_collision_player; i <= ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player; i++)
        {
            array_index = xtile_coord_left_collision_player + (i * LENGTH_OF_LEVELCOL_ARRAY);
            if(STARTING_TOWN_COLLISION[array_index] == SOLID_TILE)
            {
                blocked_coord = (xtile_coord_left_collision_player * 8) + 8;
                player_x = blocked_coord;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (player_move_right)
    {
        player_x += 1;
                
        player_right_collision_coord = player_x + PLAYER_COLBOX_RIGHT;
        xtile_coord_right_collision_player = player_right_collision_coord / 8;

        player_top_collision_coord = player_y + PLAYER_COLBOX_TOP;
        ytile_coord_top_collision_player = player_top_collision_coord / 8;

        player_bottom_collision_coord = player_y + PLAYER_COLBOX_BOTTOM;
        ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player = player_bottom_collision_coord / 8;

        for (i = ytile_coord_top_collision_player; i <= ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player; i++)
        {
            array_index = xtile_coord_right_collision_player + (i * LENGTH_OF_LEVELCOL_ARRAY);
            if(STARTING_TOWN_COLLISION[array_index] == SOLID_TILE)
            {
                blocked_coord = (xtile_coord_right_collision_player * 8) - PLAYER_COLBOX_RIGHT;
                player_x = blocked_coord;
            }
        }
    }

    if (player_move_up)
    {
        player_y -= 1;

        player_top_collision_coord = player_y + PLAYER_COLBOX_TOP;
        ytile_coord_top_collision_player = player_top_collision_coord / 8;

        player_left_collision_coord = player_x + PLAYER_COLBOX_LEFT;
        xtile_coord_left_collision_player = player_left_collision_coord / 8;

        player_right_collision_coord = player_x + PLAYER_COLBOX_RIGHT;
        xtile_coord_right_collision_player = player_right_collision_coord / 8;

        for (i = xtile_coord_left_collision_player ; i <= xtile_coord_right_collision_player ; i++)
        {
            array_index = i+ (ytile_coord_top_collision_player * LENGTH_OF_LEVELCOL_ARRAY);
            if(STARTING_TOWN_COLLISION[array_index] == SOLID_TILE)
            {
                blocked_coord = (ytile_coord_top_collision_player * 8) + 8 - PLAYER_COLBOX_TOP;
                player_y = blocked_coord;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (player_move_down)
    {
        player_y += 1;

        player_bottom_collision_coord = player_y + PLAYER_COLBOX_BOTTOM;
        ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player = player_bottom_collision_coord / 8;

        player_left_collision_coord = player_x + PLAYER_COLBOX_LEFT;
        xtile_coord_left_collision_player = player_left_collision_coord / 8;

        player_right_collision_coord = player_x + PLAYER_COLBOX_RIGHT;
        xtile_coord_right_collision_player = player_right_collision_coord / 8;

        for (i = xtile_coord_left_collision_player ; i <= xtile_coord_right_collision_player ; i++)
        {
            array_index = i+ (ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player * LENGTH_OF_LEVELCOL_ARRAY);
            if(STARTING_TOWN_COLLISION[array_index] == SOLID_TILE)
            {
                blocked_coord = (ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player * 8) - 24 + PLAYER_COLBOX_BOTTOM;
                player_y = blocked_coord;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the values for everything in the 'if (player_move_down)' function. However, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

> when you move down into something, it shoots you through the collision rather that keeping you out

That's because the computation

```
    blocked_coord = (ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player * 8) - 24 + PLAYER_COLBOX_BOTTOM;
```

is wrong - *ytile_coord_bottom_collision_player * 8* is immediately below the 2×2 tile player sprite, and the *- 24 + PLAYER_COLBOX_BOTTOM* moves from 16 pixels below 24 pixels up and 16 down, so the new y coordinate is 8 pixels lower than before.

I'd just drop this calculation and just revert the above `player_y += 1` with `player_y -= 1`.